# Как выровнять блоки с помощью flex?

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Имеется три блока: один большой и два боковых.
Подскажите, как прижать боковые блоки к краям главного блока?
т.е. чтобы боковые блоки были всегда прижаты снизу и сверху, в зависимости от размера экрана.
https://jsfiddle.net/k7L389js/

```css
.main{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-height: 766px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.left{
  width: 70%;
  flex-basis: 70%;
  padding: 5px;
}
.left-item{
   background: gray;
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
.right{
  width: 29%;
  flex-basis: 29%;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}
.right-item{
  background: gray;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  max-height: 49%;
}
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="left-item">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://images.astronet.ru/pubd/2005/02/26/0001203055/illume_wasilewski_full.small.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right-item">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://images.astronet.ru/pubd/2005/02/26/0001203055/illume_wasilewski_full.small.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="right-item">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://images.astronet.ru/pubd/2005/02/26/0001203055/illume_wasilewski_full.small.jpg" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Есть ли идеи, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Расположение блоков на второстепенной оси регулируется свойством [`align-items`](http://theory.phphtml.net/css/align-items.html). Ставим

```
.main{
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

Но свойство не будет работать, если не убрать лишние значения высоты блоков

```
.right{
  /*  height: 100%; */
}
```

Так-же активируем flex для правой колонки

```
.right{
  display: flex;
}
```

И вот и все:
https://jsfiddle.net/k7L389js/2/